# Updated nested object by matching ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I have an array with nested objects that I need to update from another array of objects, if they match.

Here is the data structure I want to update:

```
const invoices = {
 BatchItemRequest: [
 {
  bId: "bid10",
  Invoice: {
    Line: [
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10110" },
        },
      },
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "11110" },
        },
        Amount: 2499,
      },
    ],
  },
},
{
  bId: "bid10",
  Invoice: {
    Line: [
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10110" },
        },
      },
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10111" },
        },
        Amount: 2499,
      },
    ],
  },
},
],
};
```

Here is the array of objects I want to update it from:

```
const accounts = [
 { AccountCode: "10110", Id: "84" },
 { AccountCode: "11110", Id: "5" },
 { AccountCode: "10111", Id: "81" },
];
```

I want to update invoices, using accounts, by inserting Id if AccountCode matches, to get the following structure:

```
const invoices = {
 BatchItemRequest: [
 {
  bId: "bid10",
  Invoice: {
    Line: [
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10110", Id: "84" },
        },
      },
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "11110", Id: "5" },
        },
        Amount: 2499,
      },
    ],
  },
},
{
  bId: "bid10",
  Invoice: {
    Line: [
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10110", Id: "84" },
        },
      },
      {
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemAccountRef: { AccountCode: "10111", Id: "81" },
        },
        Amount: 2499,
      },
    ],
  },
},
],
};
```

I have tried various methods, such as the following:

```
const mapped = invoices.BatchItemRequest.map((item1) => {
return Object.assign(
  item1,
  accounts.find((item2) => {
    return item2 && item1.Invoice.Line.ItemAccountRef.AccountCode === item2.AccountCode;
  })
);
});
```

Problem with this approach (it doesn't work as I think I need to do another nested map), but it also creates a new array, only including the nested elements of invoices.

Does anyone know a good approach to this?

Comment: Does your `accounts` array _have_ to look like that? It would be a lot easier to work with as a map of account codes to `Id` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest of code but it gets the job done:

```
function matchInvoiceWithAccount(invoices, accounts) {
    const mappedInvoices = invoices.BatchItemRequest.map((request) => {
        // Shouldn't modify input parameter, could use Object.assign to create a copy and modify the copy instead for purity
        request.Invoice.Line = request.Invoice.Line.map((line) => {
            const accountCode = line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemAccountRef.AccountCode;
            // If accounts was a map of AccountCode to Id you would't need to search for it which would be more effective
            const account = accounts.find((account) => account.AccountCode === accountCode);

            if (account) {
                line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemAccountRef.Id = account.Id;
            }

            return line;
        });

        return request;
    });

    return {
        BatchItemRequest: mappedInvoices,
    };
}
```

What you could and probably should do to improve this is to not modify the input parameters of the function, but that requires that you in a better way copy the original, either using Object.assign or spread operator.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it will be good to create Map from your accounts array. We will go one time for array with O(n) and then will read ids by code with O(1). And nested fors is O(m*n), that will be much more slower at big arrays.

```
const idsByAccountCodes = new Map();
accounts.forEach((data) => {
    idsByAccountCodes.set(data.AccountCode, data.Id);
})
```

or shorter:

```
const idsByAccountCode = new Map(accounts.map((data) => [data.AccountCode, data.Id]))
```

then if you want to mutate original values you can go through all nesting levels and add values

```
for ( const {Invoice:{ Line: line }} of invoices.BatchItemRequest){
    for ( const {SalesItemLineDetail: {ItemAccountRef: item}} of line){
      item.Id = idsByAccountCodes.get(item.AccountCode) || 'some default value'
      // also if you don't have ids for all codes you need to define logic for  that case
    }
}
```

If you don't need to mutate original big object "invoices"  and all of nested objects, then you can create recursive clone of if with something like lodash.cloneDeep

Comment: Thank you! Works well